# HTML5, canvas: some linewidth too narrow and then disappear

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

A stupid simple canvas usage:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(100000, 100000);
ctx.lineWidth = 0.00001;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

The current line segment is not displayed。
if I change to this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(10000, 10000);
ctx.lineWidth = 0.0001;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Line segments will be displayed?
Why does this happen. It’s annoying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems to work here. What browser?

Comment: Can repro on Safari (both stable 15.4 and T.P.) Please open an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org/ Not much you can do apart from... not using such scales.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry,I wrote it wrongly ,so it worked before. I entered a new code, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in the GPU renderer used by Chrome.

We can confirm it's only a bug in the GPU pipes by initializing your context with the `willReadFrequently` flag, but that's not a proper solution (because you want GPU acceleration when available).

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
ctx.scale(100000, 100000);
ctx.lineWidth = 0.00001;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

So, it would be great to [open an issue against Chromium](https://crbug.com), you can point to them that apparently [this CL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/27eda86b25a836bf633e49fc09c03bce5892342a..4a9f0fb5093b651526b25044e1da2cac7e58488b) introduced the issue, and thus it is a regression.

While you're there, you can also open one [against WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/), which doesn't even pass the *x10,000* scale test.

But to be honest, you are asking for trouble using such scales.
Such "rounding" bugs regularly come and go in various engines, and not only this obvious, sometimes only when doing a particular curve etc.

So the best is to stick to "standard" scales, if you really need to go that far, then do the scaling yourself from JS:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const scale = 100_000;
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200 * scale, 100 * scale);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeap! thanks you so much .I also found that would work at different points.But anyway,i will avoid to using such scale.